# Boolean Program clarification for beginner

Tags: c#, random

Consider the following program:

```
using System;

class BooleanType
{
    static void Main()
    {
        bool male = false;

        Random random = new Random();
        male = Convert.ToBoolean(random.Next(0, 2));

        if (male) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We will use name John");
        } else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We will use name Victoria");
        }
    }
}
```

Question 1. why is the line `bool male = false;` initialised to false?
 this seems irrelevant to me as the program later decides if it will be true or false.

Question 2. `Random random = new Random();` Why do you have to initialise this to `new Random()`, doesn't `Random random` create the variable random of type random?

Comment: Q1 : Spot on. It's a redundant initialization. The declaration and initialization could be done on the same line after the `Random random` line.

Comment: Shouldn't questions like this one be asked on `http://codereview.stackexchange.com/` ?

Comment: @LucMorin [Nope](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1**: You are right that this is a redundant initialiser as the value is almost immediately set a few lines later. In fact, you could simplify the code slightly by combining the declaration and initialisation:

```
bool male = Convert.ToBoolean(random.Next(0, 2));
```

The one reason why the code might look the way it does is because C# mandates that all variables must be initialised before they are used and whoever wrote the code is in the habit of initialising everything. From the [official docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx#Anchor_2):

> Local variables in C# must be initialized before they are used.

**Question 2**: The `Random` type is *not* a vlue type, it is a reference type. This means that the default value for a variable of a reference type is always `null`. In other words, it is nothing, it doesn't exist and you will get an exception if you try to use it. So you must initialise it by creating an instance of the class with the [`new`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx) operator.

Comment: Q1: Not entirely true. If the value type variable is a local variable, then the compiler mandates that it be explicitly assigned a value before it is referenced.

Comment: OK, I'll clarify that, but I meant it's redundant in context of the code provided.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. It's just a point of clarification, so that people don't read this and think that it's fine to do `bool b; if (b) { ... }`

Comment: Yup, I've rejigged the post a bit.

Answer (score 0):

> why is the line bool male = false; initialised to false? this seems irrelevant to me as the program later decides if it will be true or false.

It doesn't have to be.  You could declare it as

```
bool male;
```

...which means it won't be initialized.  Although technically its memory location will be set to false, the compiler won't let you use this variable until you assign it a value; this can be helpful if you want to make sure you actually assign it something later.

> `Random random = new Random();` Why do you have to initialise this to new Random(), doesn't Random random create the variable random of type random?

If it bothers you a lot, you can also declare it as

```
 var random = new Random();
```

This may seem less redundant to you.

To the left of the symbol `random` you generally will declare a [type](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm) (in this case, the Random class) and to the right hand side ("[RHS](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?287301-what-does-quot-rhs-quot-mean-(I-m-very-curious-))") of the equal sign you will generally provide a method for creating an *instance* of that type (in this case a `new` instance, although you could assign it an existing instance).  When you use the `var` keyword, the compiler will infer the type from the RHS when possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1. why is the line bool male = false; initialised to false? this seems irrelevant to me as the program later decides if it will be true or false.

In this case, you are right it is irrelevant. But in some cases variables are initialized to a value because that will be the default. For example, one might do this:

```
bool overtime = false;

if (hours > 40)
{
    overtime = true;
}
```

In the above there is no else. If `hours` are not more than 40 then it will not be overtime.

> Question 2. Random random = new Random(); Why do you have to initialise this to new Random(), doesn't Random random create the variable random of type random?

Actually `Random random` does not create the variable. It *declares* a variable named `random` of type `Random`. The variable is `null` by default. Once you do this:

```
Random random = new Random();
```

Now the variable is holding a reference to an *instance* of `Random`. In some case people do this if one class derives from another class:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        base.DoSomething();
        Console.WriteLine(" World!");
    }
}

ClassA a = null;
```

Later on base on some decision, they may do this:

```
if (somecondition)
{
    a = new ClassB();
} 
else 
{
   a = new ClassA();
}
```

This gives you polymorphism because the reference is of type `ClassA` but the object instance is of type `ClassB` or `ClassA` depending on the condition. Now you can do this regardless of whether it is an instance of `ClassA` or `ClassB`:

```
a.DoSomething();
```

Depending on the instance, `a.DoSomething()` will either write *Hello* or *Hello World!*

The benefits are even more obvious when you do something like this:

```
List <ClassA> list = new List<ClassA>();

list.Add(new ClassA());
list.Add(new ClassB());
foreach (var thisClass in list)
{
    thisClass.DoSomething();
}
```

In the above I am creating a `List` of `ClassA` and then adding instances of `ClassA` and `ClassB` and then looping them and calling `DoSomething()` on them.

Try it and you will see how flexible this is.

Answer (score -1):

The Answer to your first Question is in the code it is initially set as false, so that it doesn't create ambiguity.
We know we set what is the default value, the response occurs according to our settings of variables.

And in the 2nd Question you asked why we used the word "new" , instead of a simple variable declaration.
So we used the word "new" because Random is a class, and for creating Class instances we must have to use the word new. (These are not simple variables) 
Hope You got.